# Acceder a un metodo de una clase php con AJax para consultas

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

Alguien me ayude a solucionar este problema para realizar peticiones de una clase.
Como puedo acceder a ese metodo(verPeticion)de la clase muestra desde el Ajax, si saco mi algoritmo del metodo verPeticion() si funciona todo, pero cuando lo agrego sale el error.

```
mostrar.php
<?php 

class muestra{

public function verPeticion(){
    
    $datos = json_decode($_POST["data"], true);
    echo json_encode($datos);
   }
}?>
```

Este es mi script para realizar la consulta

```
main.php
$.ajax({
    data : parametros,
    url : "http://localhost/API/mostrar.php/muestra/verPeticion",
    type : "POST",
    beforeSend : function(){
        console.log("Guardando");
    },
    success : function(response){
        var data = JSON.parse(response);
        
        $("#respuesta").html(response);
        $("#nombre2").val(data[0]["nombre"]);
        $("#apellido2").val(data[0]["apellido"]);
        $("#edad2").val(data[0]["edad"]);
    },
    error:function(){
        alert("Error");
    }
})
```

Este es el error que me da

```
VM35:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
at Object.success (main.php:59:29)
at c (jquery-3.6.1.min.js:2:28327)
at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-3.6.1.min.js:2:29072)
at l (jquery-3.6.1.min.js:2:80045)
at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery-3.6.1.min.js:2:82499)
```

Answer (score 0):

En el documento `mostrar.php`  solo estas definiendo la `clase muestra` y sus `metodos` pero no la estas `instanciando`  ni llamando el metodo `verPeticion()`

Modifica le codigo del documento `mostrar.php` :

```
<?php 

class muestra{
   public function verPeticion($var){
    $datos = json_decode($var, true);
    return json_encode($datos);
   }
}



$mostrar = new muestra();
echo $mostrar->verPeticion($_POST["data"]);

?>
```

**nota:** no entiendo ¿por que? : decodificas el `Json` y luego lo vuelves a codificar para mostrarlo.

> seguramente estas haciendo pruebas

.

Comment: Estoy haciendo pruebas nomas, pero la cosa seria tener varios metodos y solo querer llamar a una en especifico, este codigo lo vi de un compañero de trabajo que ya se fue y quise replicarlo, solo me dijo que los slash llaman a la clase y luego al metodo